# Why was Hogwarts so adamant about having Harry go there?

Tags: harry-potter

I was watching Fantastic Beasts and where to find them when Lumos shined above my head. It states in FB that if a wizard oppresses their power then it will turn into an obscurial/obscurios. This lead me to think that Hogwarts didnt want Harry to become an obscurios. This is because obscurioses are powerful forces that can cause a lot of havoc, and with Harry being a horcrux and having a part of Voldemort in him then he would be a very, very powerful obscurios.

Is this a reasonable reason? Or did Hogwarts just not want Harry to suffer with the Dursleys?

Comment: Harry was not an obscurus since he was not traumatized to the extent that Ariana Dumbledore or Credence Barebone were - he had the same amount of control over his powers as any other wizard.

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145472/why-wasnt-this-character-an-obscurus

Comment: [Harry's not a Horcrux](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11546/31178)

Comment: Harry is neither a Hurcrux nor an Obscurius.

Comment: Someone pinged me? ;)

Answer (score 10):

Harry was not at risk of becoming an Obscurial because he was not repressing his magic. (From JK Rowling's new website: Why didn’t Harry Potter develop an Obscurus?
An Obscurus is developed under very specific conditions: trauma associated with the use of magic, internalized hatred of one’s own magic and a conscious attempt to suppress it. http://www.jkrowling.com/welcome-to-my-new-website/ )

Hogwarts is the only school in the UK for wizards.

Hogwarts is the safest place in the UK for wizards - this is the main reason that it was important that he went: to be safe and under Dumbledore's close supervision. (Hagrid says: "There's no place safer than Gringotts, except maybe Hogwarts")

Comment: And Harry was enrolled at Hogwarts before his birth by his parents